# The strange isomorphic mapping shown in GAP: [ P, Q ] -> [ <[ [ 1, 1 ] ]|P>, <[ [ 2, 1 ] ]|Q> ].

Tags: gap

I tested the following code snippet in GAP:

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup("P" ,"Q");;
gap> G8_5:=f/ParseRelators(f, "P^4 = Q^4 = 1, Q*P = P^3*Q, Q^2 = P^2");;
gap> AssignGeneratorVariables(G8_5);
#I  Global variable `P' is already defined and will be overwritten
#I  Global variable `Q' is already defined and will be overwritten
#I  Assigned the global variables [ P, Q ]
gap> g1:=Group( Elements(G8_5) );
Group([ P, P^3, Q, P^2*Q, P^2, P*Q, P^3*Q ])
gap> IsomorphismGroups(G8_5,g1);
#I  Forcing finiteness test
[ P, Q ] -> [ <[ [ 1, 1 ] ]|P>, <[ [ 2, 1 ] ]|Q> ]
```

As you can see, it gives the description of the isomorphic mapping represented by the following relationship:

```
[ P, Q ] -> [ <[ [ 1, 1 ] ]|P>, <[ [ 2, 1 ] ]|Q> ]
```

But the form of image elements looks strange, and I failed to figure out the meaning of them. Any hints will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
HZ

Comment: This is not a question about Mathematics. You're on the wrong forum.

Comment: I think you need to more specific and explain what is "strange". Is it strange that P maps to P and Q to Q? Or, as I may guess, you haven't seen `<[ [ 1, 1 ] ]|P>` in the output before, and you'd like to know what does it mean? Note that `g1` is created as a subgroup of `G8_5`, is that would you intended to do?

Comment: 1. By "strange", I mean I can't figure out the meaning of `<[ [ 1, 1 ] ]|P>` and `<[ [ 2, 1 ] ]|Q>`, and what's the mapping action (mapping function) in detail. 2. ```gap> IsSubgroup(G8_5,g1);
true
gap> IsSubgroup(g1,G8_5);
true```, so they're subgroups of each other. Why do you only say `g1` is created as a subgroup of `G8_5`?

Comment: I am unsure what you're trying to achieve. You're generating `g1` by the whole list of `Elements(G8_5)`. Clearly `g1` it's a subgroup of `G8_5` then, and since each generator of `G8_5` is also a generator of `g1`, then `g1` coincides with `G8_5`. So they are isomorphic, and a cheaper way to establish that fact in this case is to ask `g1=G8_5` (unless you want an explicit isomorphism).

Comment: 1. My purpose: Verify that two groups are the same by using different forms of group elements based on the same generators set. The example here uses the same group, so it's not easy to explain. 2. I still want to know the implication of the symbol: `<[ [ 1, 1 ] ]|P>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation `< [[a,b],[...]]| elm >` describes elements that are (potentially) stored as a product in generators (to save on memory). The actual element is what is given between `|` and `>`, i.e. $P$ and $Q$ in your case, and these elements will compare as being equal to $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: By "product", do you mean the multiplication defined on the group? And furthermore, what's the specific product formula used here to (potentially) store the element as a product in generators when there are multiple `[ ]` pairs on the left side of the `|`?

Comment: Where is the document description of the specification?